# In Clojure, how to define a variable named by a string?

Tags: clojure, symbols, function

Given a list of names for variables, I want to set those variables to an expression.

I tried this:

```
(doall (for [x ["a" "b" "c"]] (def (symbol x) 666)))
```

...but this yields the error

> java.lang.Exception: First argument to def must be a Symbol

Can anyone show me the right way to accomplish this, please?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Clojure's "intern" function is for this purpose:

```
(doseq [x ["a" "b" "c"]]
  (intern *ns* (symbol x) 666))
```

Comment: Most concise and straightforward (possible?) answer. I've given you the tickmark and hope sepp2k isn't mad about losing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

*Updated to take Stuart Sierra's comment (mentioning `clojure.core/intern`) into account.*

Using `eval` here is fine, but it may be interesting to know that it is not necessary, regardless of whether the Vars are known to exist already. In fact, if they are known to exist, then I think the `alter-var-root` solution below is cleaner; if they might not exist, then I wouldn't insist on my alternative proposition being much cleaner, but it seems to make for the shortest code (if we disregard the overhead of three lines for a function definition), so I'll just post it for your consideration.

---

If the Var is known to exist:

```
(alter-var-root (resolve (symbol "foo")) (constantly new-value))
```

So you could do

```
(dorun
  (map #(-> %1 symbol resolve (alter-var-root %2))
       ["x" "y" "z"]
       [value-for-x value-for-y value-for z]))
```

(If the same value was to be used for all Vars, you could use `(repeat value)` for the final argument to map or just put it in the anonymous function.)

---

If the Vars might need to be created, then you can actually write a function to do this (once again, I wouldn't necessarily claim this to be cleaner than `eval`, but anyway -- just for the interest of it):

```
(defn create-var
  ;; I used clojure.lang.Var/intern in the original answer,
  ;; but as Stuart Sierra has pointed out in a comment,
  ;; a Clojure built-in is available to accomplish the same
  ;; thing
  ([sym] (intern *ns* sym))
  ([sym val] (intern *ns* sym val)))
```

Note that if a Var turns out to have already been interned with the given name in the given namespace, then this changes nothing in the single argument case or just resets the Var to the given new value in the two argument case. With this, you can solve the original problem like so:

```
(dorun (map #(create-var (symbol %) 666) ["x" "y" "z"]))
```

Some additional examples:

```
user> (create-var 'bar (fn [_] :bar))
#'user/bar
user> (bar :foo)
:bar

user> (create-var 'baz)
#'user/baz
user> baz
; Evaluation aborted. ; java.lang.IllegalStateException:
                      ;   Var user/baz is unbound.
                      ; It does exist, though!

;; if you really wanted to do things like this, you'd
;; actually use the clojure.contrib.with-ns/with-ns macro
user> (binding [*ns* (the-ns 'quux)]
        (create-var 'foobar 5))
#'quux/foobar
user> quux/foobar
5
```

Comment: Very cool and very informative, thanks a lot! At first glance this looks to be doing what the code for `def` does; I guess it's a "forked" `def`. I may use this on my next mini-project.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Don't use eval until its necessary and you know what you're doing. I'd go with intern for solving the problem at hand; this answer showed nicely that eval is not needed here.

Comment: Var.intern is available as the built-in Clojure function "intern"

Comment: @Stuart: Thanks for the comment! I guess I ought to re-familiarise myself with the core API... I'll work this into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Evaluation rules for normal function calls are to evaluate all the items of the list, and call the first item in the list as a function with the rest of the items in the list as parameters.

But you can't make any assumptions about the evaluation rules for special forms or macros.  A special form or the code produced by a macro call could evaluate all the arguments, or never evaluate them, or evaluate them multiple times, or evaluate some arguments and not others.  `def` is a special form, and it doesn't evaluate its first argument.  If it did, it couldn't work.  Evaluating the `foo` in `(def foo 123)` would result in a "no such var 'foo'" error most of the time (if `foo` was already defined, you probably wouldn't be defining it yourself).

I'm not sure what you're using this for, but it doesn't seem very idiomatic.  Using `def` anywhere but at the toplevel of your program usually means you're doing something wrong.

(Note: `doall` + `for` = `doseq`.)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about `doseq`! I'm defining a handful of variables at the top level and just wanted to cut down on typing.

Comment: Why not use symbols to begin with then, instead of strings?

Comment: Because the names I was planning to use were themselves computed (by concatenation, natch). I emphasize that I do this only for purposes of experimental, "quick and dirty" code; there are much better ways to express what I'm doing. I posted this question only because I wanted to do this in my early-draft code and was annoyed that the otherwise excellent Clojure language seemed not to support this particular jiggerpokery.

Comment: I'm still exploring the Lisp idiom and Clojure in particular. I do not plan to make dynamically created named global variables part of my regular programming repertoire.