# Recommended ways to debug Clojure functions?

Tags: debugging, clojure

My current method: if there's a function that I know has an bug, I copy bits and pieces of it into the REPL and evaluate to see if the output is what I expect. To set it up, I have to def the arguments to the function as dummy input. Not terribly time-consuming, but I know there's a more efficient way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just found, and learned a lot from, this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352020/debugging-in-clojure, but if anyone has thoughts with respect to my specific case (debugging the output of a (purely functional) function) I would "accept" your good ideas! Thanks

Comment: +1 because I wish I knew anything about Lisp-related languages

Comment: I'm still learning the basics, but if I were to need to leap ahead to debugging an actual script/module, I would check out a unit testing package: `clojure.contrib.test-is` is one; IIRC there are one or two others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this macro help? It turns a let into a series of defs, so that you can evaluate the subexpressions:

```
(defmacro def-let
  "like let, but binds the expressions globally."
  [bindings & more]
  (let [let-expr (macroexpand `(let ~bindings))
        names-values (partition 2 (second let-expr))
        defs   (map #(cons 'def %) names-values)]
    (concat (list 'do) defs more)))
```

I wrote an explanation here: 
http://www.learningclojure.com/2010/09/astonishing-macro-of-narayan-singhal.html

Comment: ooh, that is pretty astonishing!

Answer (score 2):

After reading up on this, my new favorite method is to add

```
(swank.core/break)
```

inside the function and inspect values by pressing 't'. (I'm using swank-clojure)

Source:
http://hugoduncan.org/post/2010/swank_clojure_gets_a_break_with_the_local_environment.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

for bugs spanning several functions I like the [Trace macro](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/trace-api.html) for reporting the calls and returns of each function.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an tracing library which can show you what value every element returned.
[http://github.com/hozumi/eyewrap](http://bit.ly/dcHMTz)

Comment: How does this compare with the `dotrace` macro in `clojure.contrib.trace`?  They seem to have similar goals/functionality.

Comment: Difference is subtle. dotrace can trace specified function deeply in every function which target function calls. eyewrap traces all elements in target function and shows you shallow results.

Answer (score 1):

Function version of def-let, some credit goes to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486752/in-clojure-how-to-define-a-variable-named-by-a-string).

```
(defn def-let [aVec]
  (if-not (even? (count aVec))
    aVec
    (let [aKey (atom "")       
          counter (atom 0)]
      (doseq [item aVec]
        (if (even? @counter) 
          (reset! aKey  item)           
          (intern *ns*  (symbol @aKey)  (eval item)))
        ;   (prn  item)       
    (swap! counter inc)))))
```

Usage: Needs to quote the content with a quotation, e.g.

```
(def-let '[a 1 b 2 c (atom 0)])
```