# Why I'm getting Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use dotrace function of clojure.tools.trace namespace.

```
(dotrace [my-function] (my-function 5))
```

But I got this error:

> IllegalStateException Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: my-ns/my-function   clojure.lang.Var.pushThreadBindings (Var.java:339)

What does it mean? why I'm getting it?

(I'm using Clojure 1.3)

Comment: Can you also specify the code for my-function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need to declare your function as being dynamically bound, e.g.

```
(def ^:dynamic my-function
   (fn [x] .....))
```

The reason for that is because if you don't explicitly ask for a dynamic var, Clojure (1.3 upwards) will make it non-dynamic as a performance optimization.

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't this be `defn`?

Comment: Either `def` or `defn` should be fine, you can use either to define your function (edited to make clear)