# How do I get the argument in a macro from a map macro in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, macros, clojure

I'm passing my macro to a map operation (which is also a macro). I'm having some trouble getting my values out. Here is an example:

```
(def num-vec [1 2 3 4 5])

(defmacro describe-args [first-arg & remaining-args]
  `(println '~first-arg '~remaining-args))

(doall (map #(describe-args "my args " %) num-vec))
```

This returns:

```
  my args  (p1__432#)
  my args  (p1__432#)
  my args  (p1__432#)
  my args  (p1__432#)
  my args  (p1__432#)
```

My question is: **How do I get the argument in a macro from a map macro in Clojure?**

(I believe this is a different question to the other map/macro questions already asked as this is about *argument retrieval*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change macro `describe-args` to:

```
(defmacro describe-args [desc & args]
  `(println ~desc ~@args))
```

Now

```
(doall (map #(describe-args "my args " %) num-vec))
```

prints

```
my args  1
my args  2
my args  3
my args  4
my args  5
```

More general debugging macro is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2352280/4430998).

Comment: `'~desc` - the `'` (quote) is not needed here. It is expanding to `(quote "my args ")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is you want

```
(defmacro print-second [form]
  (if (list? form) 
     `(do (println '~(second form) " = " ~(second form)) ~form)
     form))

(def num-vec [1 2 3 4 5])

(doall (map #(print-second (+ (* 3 42) %)) num-vec))
```

=>

```
;(* 3 42)  =  126
;(* 3 42)  =  126
;(* 3 42)  =  126
;(* 3 42)  =  126
;(* 3 42)  =  126
(127 128 129 130 131)


(print-second (+ 99 7))
```

=>

```
;99  =  99
106

(print-second 3)
```

=>

```
3
```

Comment: That's awesome. Here is a harder one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645530/how-do-i-get-the-nested-argument-in-a-macro-inside-a-mapped-function-in-clojure