# clojure.java.jdbc/query large resultset lazily

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to read millions of rows from a database and write to a text file.

This is a continuation of my question [database dump to text file with side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696682/database-dump-to-text-file-with-side-effects-for-rows-completed)

My problem now seems to be that the logging doesn't happen until the program completes.  Another indicator that i'm not processing lazily is that the text file isn't written at all until the program finishes.

Based on an IRC tip it seems my issue is likely having to do with `:result-set-fn`and defaulting to `doall` in the `clojure.java.jdbc/query` area of the code.

I have tried to replace this with a `for` function but still discover that memory consumption is high as it pulls the entire result set into memory.

How can i have a `:result-set-fn` that doesn't pull everything in like `doall`?  How can I progressively write the log file as the program is running, rather then dump everything once the `-main` execution is finished?

```
    (let [ 
          db-spec              local-postgres
          sql                  "select * from public.f_5500_sf "
          log-report-interval  1000
          fetch-size           100
          field-delim          "\t"                                                                  
          row-delim            "\n"                                                                  
          db-connection        (doto ( j/get-connection db-spec) (.setAutoCommit false)) 
          statement            (j/prepare-statement db-connection sql :fetch-size fetch-size ) 
          joiner               (fn [v] (str (join field-delim v ) row-delim ) )                      
          start                (System/currentTimeMillis)                                            
          rate-calc            (fn [r] (float (/ r (/ ( - (System/currentTimeMillis) start) 100))))  
          row-count            (atom 0)                                                              
          result-set-fn        (fn [rs] (lazy-seq rs))
          lazy-results         (rest (j/query db-connection [statement] :as-arrays? true :row-fn joiner :result-set-fn result-set-fn)) 
          ]; }}}
      (.setAutoCommit db-connection false)
      (info "Started dbdump session...")    
      (with-open [^java.io.Writer wrtr (io/writer "output.txt")]
        (info "Running query...")    
        (doseq [row lazy-results] 
          (.write wrtr row)
          ))  
        (info (format "Completed write with %d rows"   @row-count))
      )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took the recent fixes for `clojure.java.jdbc` by putting `[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.0-beta1"]` in my project.clj dependencies listing.  This one enhances/corrects the `:as-arrays? true` functionality of `clojure.java.jdbc/query` described [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/JDBC-72).

I think this helped somewhat however I may still have been able to override the `:result-set-fn` to `vec`.

The core issue was resolved by tucking all row logic into `:row-fn`. The initial OutOfMemory problems had to do with iterating through `j/query` result sets rather than defining the specific `:row-fn`.

New (working) code is  below:

```
(defn -main []
  (let [; {{{
        db-spec              local-postgres
        source-sql           "select * from public.f_5500 "
        log-report-interval  1000
        fetch-size           1000
        row-count            (atom 0)
        field-delim          "\u0001"   ; unlikely to be in source feed,
                                        ; although i should still check in
                                        ; replace-newline below (for when "\t"
                                        ; is used especially) 
        row-delim            "\n" ; unless fixed-width, target doesn't
                                  ; support non-printable chars for recDelim like 
        db-connection        (doto ( j/get-connection db-spec) (.setAutoCommit false))
        statement            (j/prepare-statement db-connection source-sql :fetch-size fetch-size :concurrency :read-only)
        start                (System/currentTimeMillis)
        rate-calc            (fn [r] (float (/ r (/ ( - (System/currentTimeMillis) start) 100))))
        replace-newline      (fn [s] (if (string? s) (clojure.string/replace  s #"\n" " ") s))
        row-fn               (fn [v] 
                               (swap! row-count inc)
                               (when (zero? (mod @row-count log-report-interval))
                                 (info (format "wrote %d rows" @row-count))
                                 (info (format "\trows/s %.2f"  (rate-calc @row-count)))
                                 (info (format "\tPercent Mem used %s "  (memory-percent-used))))
                               (str (join field-delim (doall (map #(replace-newline %) v))) row-delim ))
        ]; }}}
    (info "Started database table dump session...")
    (with-open [^java.io.Writer wrtr (io/writer "./sql/output.txt")]
      (j/query db-connection [statement] :as-arrays? true :row-fn 
               #(.write wrtr (row-fn %))))
    (info (format "\t\t\tCompleted with %d rows" @row-count))
    (info (format "\t\t\tCompleted in %s seconds" (float (/ (- (System/currentTimeMillis) start) 1000))))
    (info (format "\t\t\tAverage rows/s %.2f"  (rate-calc @row-count)))
    nil)
  )
```

Other things i experimented (with limited success) involved the timbre logging and turning off stardard out;  i wondered if with using a REPL it might cache the results before displaying back to my editor (vim fireplace) and i wasn't sure if that was utilizing a lot of the memory.

Also, I added the logging parts around memory free with  `(.freeMemory (java.lang.Runtime/getRuntime))`.  I wasn't as familiar with VisualVM and pinpointing exactly where my issue was.

I am happy with how it works now, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`prepare-statement`](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/prepare-statement) with the `:fetch-size` option. Otherwise, the query itself is eager despite the results being delivered in a lazy sequence.

`prepare-statement` requires a connection object, so you'll need to explicitly create one. Here's an example of how your usage might look:

```
(let [db-spec    local-postgres
      sql        "select * from big_table limit 500000 "
      fetch-size 10000 ;; or whatever's appropriate
      cnxn       (doto (j/get-connection db-spec)
                   (.setAutoCommit false))
      stmt       (j/prepare-statement cnxn sql :fetch-size fetch-size)
      results    (rest (j/query cnxn [stmt]))]
  ;; ...
  )
```

**Another option**

Since the problem seems to be with `query`, try `with-query-results`. It's considered deprecated but is still there and works. Here's an example usage:

```
(let [db-spec    local-postgres
      sql        "select * from big_table limit 500000 "
      fetch-size 100 ;; or whatever's appropriate
      cnxn       (doto (j/get-connection db-spec)
                   (.setAutoCommit false))
      stmt       (j/prepare-statement cnxn sql :fetch-size fetch-size)]
  (j/with-query-results results [stmt] ;; binds the results to `results`
    (doseq [row results]
      ;;
      )))
```

Comment: I've added the connection, made the :result-type forward-only, added cursors, made it :read-only, and set the fetch-size to 1000, and then 100.  I'm still running out of jvm heap size when i try to fetch larger result sets.  I've updated my question above to include the new code... i'm at a loss as to what could be eager at this point...

Comment: @joefromct, try disabling autocommit - `(.setAutoCommit db-connection false)`. I added it to the sample code in my answer. As an aside, part of the difficulty is that `setFetchSize` is merely a hint to the driver ([per the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int))) so how it's interpreted can vary between drivers. However, PostgreSQL's [JDBC docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html) indicate it's supported so I think we just need to find the right incantation.

Comment: To clarify, `setFetchSize` is a method `prepare-statement` invokes internally based on the `:fetch-size` argument, not something additional you need in your code.

Comment: @joefromct, I just realized I had an error in the example I added last night. You need to call `.setAutoCommit` *before* running the query. I've corrected the example. Sorry about that - I was a bit tired.

Comment: still no luck.... i've added the .setAutocommit before the query was issued. I have also talked to some folks in the IRC chat and somebody opened up this:  http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/JDBC-72  

I have updated my code to reflect my latest attempt with your suggestions.  OutOfMemory JavaHeapSpace.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is in the lib. Well, if it's in `query` let's try a different route. I added an example of `with-query-results` at the bottom of my answer. I haven't tested it yet but will when I get a chance later. In the mean time give it a shot if you're able and see if it helps.

Comment: ugh... with-query-results doesn't have an :as-arrays? param i can pass in.  That leaves me without knowing the exact column ordinal as the map might not be in order.  I'm keeping at it though, and i'll keep you posted.

Comment: The change from the bug you referenced is in `clojure.java.jdbc` 0.3.0 beta 1, which was [released the other day](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&shva=1#search/label%3Aclojure-clojure+jdbc/14224946278dbf8c). Have you given it a try?

Comment: I have, and i have finally gotten large result sets to consume little memory... very excited about this.  Another rule (after talking to the bug-fix person in IRC) was to try to utilize as much logic in :row-fn as possible.... i'll post my successful function shortly.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765943/clojure-java-jdbc-lazy-query/50589249#50589249

Answer (score 2):

I've have found a better solution: you need to declare a cursor and fetch chunks of data from it in a transaction. Example:

```
  (db/with-tx
    (db/execute! "declare cur cursor for select * from huge_table")
    (loop []
      (when-let [rows (-> "fetch 10 from cur" db/query not-empty)]
        (doseq [row rows]
          (process-a-row row))
        (recur))))
```

Here, `db/with-tx`, `db/execute!` and `db/query` are my own shortcuts declared in `db` namespace:

```
(def ^:dynamic
  *db* {:dbtype "postgresql"
        :connection-uri <some db url>)})

(defn query [& args]
  (apply jdbc/query *db* args))

(defn execute! [& args]
  (apply jdbc/execute! *db* args))

(defmacro with-tx
  "Runs a series of queries into transaction."
  [& body]
  `(jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx# *db*]
     (binding [*db* tx#]
       ~@body)))
```

Comment: thanks for that, i'll give it a shot.  It is unfortunate that specific pg sql syntax has to be used in the `db/execute!` however.  I was practicing on postgres but trying to build something somewhat database agnostic.  Thanks,