# Elapsed time in lazy sequence evaluation

Tags: time, clojure, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

Given this code:

```
(reduce my-fun my-lazy-seq)
```

To measure the elapsed time of the entire operation:

```
(time (reduce my-fun my-lazy-seq))  ;;Elapsed time: 1000.1234 msecs
```

How do I measure the elapsed time of this loop at various stages before completion?  For example:

```
Elapsed time to process next 1000 samples in my-lazy-seq: 100.1234 msecs  
Elapsed time to process next 1000 samples in my-lazy-seq: 99.1234 msecs  
Elapsed time to process next 1000 samples in my-lazy-seq: 101.1234 msecs  
...
```

Comment: I think a solution would be to convert the lazy sequence into a lazy sequence of batches of size 1000, and put the time around processing of each batch... but I am not sure how to do the first step in a clean way, given the origin code is already so simple and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(doseq [thousand (partition 1000 my-lazy-seq)]
  (time (reduce my-fun thousand)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
(defn seq-counter [n coll]
  (let [t0 (System/currentTimeMillis)
        f (fn [i x]
            (let [i (inc i)]
              (if (= 0 (rem i n))
                (println i "items processed in" (- (System/currentTimeMillis) t0) "ms.")) 
              x))]
    (map-indexed f coll)))
```

`map-indexed` used to check the progress. The above function will print the count and processing time in every `n` elements.

```
user=> (reduce + (seq-counter 10 (range 100)))
10 items processed in 0 ms.
20 items processed in 0 ms.
...
100 items processed in 1 ms.
4950
```

Refer to [Idiomatic clojure for progress reporting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022911/idiomatic-clojure-for-progress-reporting)

Comment: A very minor adjustment, since `if` has only one branch, you can put a `when`